# Why ismember doesn't work properly in my program in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, assign

In this part of my programme I would like to assign the **ID** variable to the **RealTagID** variable. Then in the second part I'm trying to assign the **ID** variable to the **RealTagID_NEW**. The ID variable is from my measurement data, I have uploaded it below (it's coming from the EPC). It's not working how I want, becuase for the Matlab 9B and BB is the same for some reason in the first part...

Here is my code:

```
 close all
clc

RealTagID=['A3 ' ;'A1 ' ; '9F '  ;'9D ' ; '9B ' ; 'A9 '  ; 'A7 ' ; 'A5 ' ];
%The last two characters of the EPC code of the tags
RealPOSX=[40 31 0 -31 -40 -32 0 +31]; 
%The x positions of fixed tags
RealPosY=[0 27 40 27 0 -27 -40 -27];
% The y positions of fixed tags

for i=1:length(XLocalization)
    temp=Epc{i};
    ID(i,:)=temp(end-2:end);
    %Makes a new variable, called 'ID', which is the last two characters from
    %the measured EPC codes
end

for i =1  :length(RealPOSX)

    idx = all(ismember(ID,RealTagID(i,:)),2)
    pos=find(idx==1);
    POS{i}=pos;
end
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RealPOSX_NEW=[20 17 0 -17 -20 -17 0 17]; 
%The x positions of fixed tags
RealPosY_NEW=[0 12 20 12 0 -12 -20 -12];
% The y positions of fixed tags
RealTagID_NEW=['B3 ' ;'B5 ' ; 'B7 '  ;'BB ' ; 'AD ' ; 'AB '  ; 'AF ' ; 'B1 ' ];
%The last two characters of the EPC code of the tags

for i =1  :length(RealPOSX_NEW)
    idxx = all(ismember(ID,RealTagID_NEW(i,:)),2)
    poss=find(idxx==1);
    POSS{i}=poss;


end
```

In the second part it's even worth. For the matlab in that case B1 is equal with BB, also B3 with BB, B5 with BB, B7 with BB and AB with BB.

I want to compare them, if they are the same, then let's be logical 1 if not then 0. But it's not working like that, because of this BB variable or I don't know.

I'm using ismember function, but it seems that it's not the best choice. Any idea? What should I use?

So my goal is to make the POS and POSS variables equal, that means all of them should be an 1x8 cells and have 58 elements of each cells. Now some of them have 116, because in that case for the matlab BB is also equal with 9B, B1, B3, B5, B7, B9. So it not good like that, BB should be equal just with BB not with this other variables as well.

Here is my measurement [Measurement](https://www.dropbox.com/s/89244wa6faf4khn/Test%2011.1%20-%20Height-100cm%2C%20Disabled%20Antennas%20-%20%2C%20TxPowerInDbm-27.25%2C%20UpdateIntervalSeconds-60%2C%20ComputeWindowSeconds-5%2C%20ReaderMode_AutoSetDenseReader%2C%20TagAgeIntervalSeconds-80%2C%20tags%2816%29%2040%20and%2020%20cm%20from%20origo.txt?dl=0)

I hope you can help me, I spent all of my day on it with no progress.

Comment: I *think* the reason that you're having trouble is that `BB` is not a single array element, it is a character array with 2 elements. `ismember('BB', '9B')` will demonstrate this error. Beyond that, your question has a lot of superfluous information that doesn't help us answer your real question, and your code is not executable because you don't define several of the variables. Please provide a [mcve] with your desired results.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I corrected it! I forgeted that RealPOSX was needed to the second loop. I also chancged the text, I hope now it's more clear what my question is.

I think you are right, but I still don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Anybody any idea?

Comment: I would probably use `strcmp`, but you'd still have to use a loop since it's not vectorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it with `strfind`.
Here is my code, it's working perfectly.

```
close all
clc
RealPOSX=[40 31 1 -31 -40 -32 1 +31]; 
%The x positions of fixed tags
RealPosY=[1 27 40 27 1 -27 -40 -27];
% The y positions of fixed tags
RealTagID=['A3 ' ;'A1 ' ; '9F '  ;'9D ' ; '9B ' ; 'A9 '  ; 'A7 ' ; 'A5 ' ];

for i=1:length(XLocalization)
    temp=Epc{i};
    ID(i,:)=temp(end-2:end);

end



for i =1  :length(RealPOSX)        
    idx = strfind(string(ID), RealTagID(i,:))

    pos= find(not(cellfun('isempty', idx)))
    POS{i}=pos;
   end

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RealPOSX_NEW=[20 17 0 -17 -20 -17 0 17]; 
%The x positions of fixed tags
RealPosY_NEW=[0 12 20 12 0 -12 -20 -12];
% The y positions of fixed tags
RealTagID_NEW=['B3 ' ;'B5 ' ; 'B7 '  ;'BB ' ; 'AD ' ; 'AB '  ; 'AF ' ; 'B1 ' ];
%The last two characters of the EPC code of the tags

for i =1  :length(RealPOSX)
    %idxx = all(ismember(ID,RealTagID_NEW(i,:)),2)
    %poss=find(idxx==1);
    idxx = strfind(string(ID), RealTagID_NEW(i,:)) 
    poss= find(not(cellfun('isempty', idxx)))
    POSS{i}=poss;
```